# Remove scrollbar from Bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, scrollbar

I want to remove Scroll bar from appearing in Bootstraps Modal so that I can use a scroll bar plugin so as to get similar scroll bar throughout the app.

I tried doing

overflow-y:hidden;

But it just disabled the scroll bar and is still appearing in Mozilla and IE.

Comment: Could you possibly make a jsfiddle? Usually the scrollbar plugin should override the default scrollbar.

Comment: I am able to use plugins scroll bar but the issue is even after making overflow-y:hidden; it just gets disabled and is still visible, the scroll bar is not getting hidden